# remove index from url wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url

How can I remove index.php from url in wordpress on IIS 2.0 server.
my htacess is like below , but it did not worked for me

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, your rewrite settings are correct. You also need to provide the correct configuration for wordpress. Go to `Settings > Permalinks` and check if you have set everything you need there. Choose something, but not "default".

**Edit**

arr, you're on IIS. You don't have a `mod_rewrite` module there because mod_rewrite is an apache module. Remove the `<ifModule>` tags and try again.

Comment: when I change it to "%postname%/" rather than "/index.php/%postname%/", the pages become not find